# VBA to change cell value based on drop down selection

Tags: vba, excel

I'm really not fantastic with VBA and have finally come to a halt.

I'm trying to automatically change 2 cell values (in the same row) based on what selection I make from a drop down.

```
Column L - Drop down consists of Won, Lost, Quote 

Column H - GO% 

Column I - GET%
```

**What I'm trying to achieve -**

```
If "Won" selected, then GO and GET cells equal 100%

If "Lost selected, then GO and GET cells equal 0%
```

I can use this formula to achieve the result but I also need users to be able to manually enter data into the GO and GET cells, effectively wiping the formula `=IF($L5="Won",1,IF($L5="Lost",0,""))`

My data starts in row 5 but I'll need this to loop as I have 500 rows of the same.

Thanks so much in advance if anyone can help :)

#### screenshot of the spreadsheet

[image: screenshot of spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will be trigger when the cell's value change, if the target fall in controlRng

Below code cannot add in Module, must be attach with the worksheet you applied Dropdown list. 
In my example is Sheet1, as shown below:

[image]

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim controlRng, nRng As Range
    Set controlRng = Range("E2:E500")
    Set nRng = Intersect(controlRng, Target)

    If nRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Value = "Won" Then
        Target.Offset(0, -4) = 1
        Target.Offset(0, -3) = 1

    ElseIf Target.Value = "Lost" Then
        Target.Offset(0, -4) = 0
        Target.Offset(0, -3) = 0
    Else
        'Do Something
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Eric, this did not seem to work for me. I've edited my question and added a screen shot to try and explain

Answer (score 1):

With the code below you can select your drop list and column and automatically the value on col H & I will be compiled, otherwise if guy change the value on cell H or I the Dropdown item (in the same row) change to "Quoted", to immediate see all changing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim controlRng, nRng As Range
    Set controlRng = Range("L2:L500", "H2:I500")
    Set nRng = Intersect(controlRng, Target)
Application.EnableEvents = False
    If nRng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Select Case Target.Column
    Case 12
        If Target.Value = "Won" Then
            Target.Offset(0, -4) = 1
            Target.Offset(0, -3) = 1

        ElseIf Target.Value = "Lost" Then
            Target.Offset(0, -4) = 0
            Target.Offset(0, -3) = 0
        Else
            'Do Something
        End If
    Case 8
        Target.Offset(0, 4) = "Quoted"
    Case 9
        Target.Offset(0, 3) = "Quoted"
    End Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```